# SvelteKit pre-rendering doesn't seem to work

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, sveltekit

This is my index.svelte

```
<script>

  import {prerendering} from '$app/env';

</script>

<script context="module">

  export const prerender=true;

</script>

<main>
   <h1>Hello world! prerendering : {prerendering}</h1>
</main>
```

I'm prerendering this page and after build, I get the pre rendered HTML file ( in the prerendered directory) with the `prerendering` inside h1 set to true.
When I serve the app using `node build` and disable JS in browser, I get `Hello world! prerendering : false`.
So clearly,the pre rendered page is not being served by the server.
I am using `adapter-node` during build.

Any ideas why this is happening?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you enabled `prerender` in `svelte.config`? You have to do that first to be able to use it in your project.