# Trying to run "npm run build" gives an error about "add `export const prerender = true` to your root `+layout.js/.ts`" even though I did that already

Tags: sveltekit

I am trying to `npm run build` to get a `/build` folder I can put on my AWS instance and deploy.

The error I get is:

```
Run npm run preview to preview your production build locally.

> Using @sveltejs/adapter-static
  @sveltejs/adapter-static: all routes must be fully prerenderable, but found the following routes that are dynamic:
    - src/routes/
  
  You have the following options:
    - set the `fallback` option — see https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#spa-mode for more info.
    - add `export const prerender = true` to your root `+layout.js/.ts` or `+layout.server.js/.ts` file. This will try to prerender all pages.
    - add `export const prerender = true` to any `+server.js/ts` files that are not fetched by page `load` functions.
  
    - pass `strict: false` to `adapter-static` to ignore this error. Only do this if you are sure you don't need the routes in question in your final app, as they will be unavailable. See https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#strict for more info.
  
  If this doesn't help, you may need to use a different adapter. @sveltejs/adapter-static can only be used for sites that don't need a server for dynamic rendering, and can run on just a static file server.
  See https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#prerender for more details
error during build:
Error: Encountered dynamic routes
```

The line I follow says: "add `export const prerender = true` to your root `+layout.js/.ts` or `+layout.server.js/.ts` file. This will try to prerender all pages."

But I followed the directions and did this to `+layout.svelte`:

```
<script>
  import '../app.css'
  export const prerender = true
</script>

<slot />
```

Why doesn't it work?

I saw [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67056512/sveltekit-pre-rendering-doesnt-seem-to-work) saying to put

```
<script context="module">

  export const prerender=true; // +layout.svelte

</script>
```

but it fails

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Delete *everything* from `+layout.ts` and replace it with just

`export const prerender = true`

that's legit the whole file.